# Chrome App: launch link in Chrome rather than Safari

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome (packaged) app which maintains a set of bookmarks. This opens in its own small window. Clicking on a bookmark opens it in a browser using a link with target set to '_blank'.

On Mac OS X, these open in Safari. Is there anyway of having them open in Chrome?

Comment: Yes. Set your default browser to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a link with target="_blank" in a packaged app, Chrome respects your choice of the default browser and opens the link externally in whatever it is, not necessarily Chrome. In your case, the default system browser must be Safari.

The easy way to open such links in Chrome would be to make it the default browser instead.

If you don't want to do that, but still for some reason insist that your links open in new tabs specifically in Chrome, here is one (perhaps the only) way to achieve that:

1. Write a companion extension to your app and have your users install it.
2. In the app, attach an onclick handler to every link, and use chrome.runtime.sendMessage() to send a request to the extension to open the link's URL (in order to do that, you will have to find out your extension's ID and bake it into its manifest, as described here: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/key.html):

   ```
   var link = ...;
   link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
       yourExtensionId, { url: link.href }, function(response) {}
     );
   };
   ```
3. In the extension, define a chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal(data) handler (it will intercept sendMessage() requests from the app), and use chrome.tabs.create() in there to open a new tab:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
     function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
       // Don't forget to make sure that |sender| is you app here.
       chrome.tabs.create({ url: request.url }, function() {
         // If you need to notify the app when the tab opens:
         sendResponse(true);
       });
       // 'true' means that your response is sent asynchronously.
       return true;
     }
   );
   ```